# Singleton pattern - a simplified implementation?

Tags: c#, singleton, resharper

The singleton pattern implementation suggested in [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) is

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

ReSharper suggests to simplify this using an auto property and the C# 6 auto-property initializer:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();
}
```

This does indeed look simpler. Is there a down-side to using this simplification?

Comment: No, it's just that the edition of C# in depth was written before C#6 was released

Comment: Yup, I haven't got round to updating the web site for C# 6.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you think you'll have the time to update the paper version for C#7? It's been almost 4 years without a new edition if I'm not mistaken ;)

Comment: @vc74: It's already in early access: https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth-fourth-edition

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks ! ordering today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On site https://sharplab.io you can look at IL code, in both cases IL code are similar. So this should work same way.